# What should I do with an old answer that needs improvement?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267939/how-to-take-the-ln-of-a-function-in-python) a couple years ago, that recently got my attention due to receiving a downvote. When I looked back at the question, I realize that even though the OP selected my answer, I actually would recommend a different approach if I were to answer the question today. So I have several options, none of which I'm particularly fond of at the moment

**Option 1:** Instead of using `map` as my current answer suggests, instead use `numpy.log` since that would be faster (although `map` does indeed return the correct result).
**Problem:** This is essentially what [@Roger Fan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25268186/2296458) suggested, so I do not want to appear to be copying their answer

**Option 2:** Delete my answer. Then instead of essentially duplicating the other answer, I will just defer to their answer and remove mine.
**Problem:** I am unable to do so, I receive the message "You cannot delete this accepted answer"

**Option 3:** Add a comment to the post to suggest the OP accepts the other answer instead of mine. This way the accepted answer is the (IMHO) preferred solution, then my solution is there as the (unpreferred) alternative.
**Problem:** The OP may be inactive on StackOverflow as it appears they have no activity in over a year, so they may never see the comment.

Any suggestions on how to handle this situation? I know it's not really a big deal, but it is a situation I've run into before. As we all gain experience, I'm sure we all go back to our old answers and would suggest a different solution if we knew then what we know now.

Comment: You cannot do anything about the acceptanceness of the answer; and totally revising it would also be unacceptable. Did you upvote the better answer? That ought to be enough (at least for those looking beyond the Big Green Mark).

Comment: @RadLexus I did indeed upvote the other answer.

Comment: I have seen a couple of posts that added a disclaimer to the top of their posts which stated that this solution is correct (at the timepoint answered) but outdated now and also were referencing to other posts that are preferrable to this one. Some also added a visual line break (`---`)  to separate their update from the old code

Comment: Just for completeness, is part of your problem description that your answer might continue to collect downvotes over time?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can amend your answer (or post a comment below it) to explain that you no longer recommend the solution, and refer to the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

Option 3 is the most appropriate. I agree that it is problematic, but we should fix that with future features on Stack Overflow, rather than butchering an old, established, answer, fundamentally changing its meaning and silently invalidating everyone's existing answers.

Don't fundamentally change an answer.

Comment: [Comments are disposable: unlike posts, there's no revision history, and they can be deleted without warning by their authors, by moderators, and in response to flags.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/300504). Isn't there a happy medium between completely rewriting the old answer, and leaving it completely untouched with now incorrect information?

Comment: @Zev: You're right; I misread the question. I thought Option 3 was a "note" at the top of the answer suggesting that it should be considered historical. But my main point is not to actually rewrite the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I would try one of the following things

1) I would add the reason at the top of my answer like

> **Edit:** Answer by *`user_name`* works faster than mine because of *`reason`*.

2) If there is a much better way than all the posted answers, I would spend a little more time and improve my answer.